# Sublime text unusual title

Tags: unity-dash, sublime-text

Whilst using Ubuntu, it occurred to me that Sublime Text 3 was showing a peculiar name on the side bar. For example, when I hover over Firefox, I get a label next to the icon saying `Firefox Web browser`, but with sublime text, it says `/var/www/html/forum/index.php - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)`. This is strange because this filename is not open in Sublime Text but still displays on the label. How can i reset it so it displays only as `Sublime Text` again?
It even says `/var/www/html/forum/index.php - Sublime Text (UNREGISTERED)` in the Dash Home

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure how it could happen, but *some* process must have either created- or edited the local `sublime-text.desktop` file.

#### How to solve?

If you installed `Sublime Text` globally (and thus the file `/usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop` exists) simply remove the local one:

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop
```

and log out/in to make Unity find the global one.

If `/usr/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop` does *not* exist, open the local one:

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/sublime-text.desktop
```

and look for the first line, starting with `Name=`. Then replace the line by:

```
Name=Sublime Text
```

Comment: note that the file is called `sublime_text.desktop` for me (`_` not `-`) in Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 and Sublime Text 3103 and 3111