# Sublime Text's Shortcut name is wrong (and creates a new file every time I start it)

Tags: shortcuts, sublime-text

I just installed Sublime Text 3 to try a rich text editor over a whole IDE. Turns out the shortcut to it is incorrect (`./theme.sh`), and every time I start Sublime it creates a file (`theme.sh`). `theme.sh` was the first file I opened with Sublime. It was a script to theme zsh.

[image: Pic]

Comment: Could you go to `/usr/share/applications/` directory, look for `sublime_text.desktop` or something similar and add its content if exists?

Comment: File exists, this is the content :

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Alunduyn/l2cpp/master/temp

Edit : no idea how to markup. Added a link to avoid a unreadable stack of stuff

Comment: try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/717380/531664